# Converting TStringlist to string with delimiter

Tags: delphi, tstringlist

I have a list of strings stored in TStringList, i want to convert it into string seperated by commas and i use the following code

```
channelList: TStringList;
aCurrentChannel :=  Stringreplace(channelList.Text,Char(13)+Char(10),',',[rfReplaceAll]);
```

but the last character is coming as , like 1,2, is there anyway to avoid that?

Comment: TStringList has a CommaText Property

Comment: As JamesB wrote, there is `CommaText` property, but using `Trim()` should fix your original solution ie `StringReplace(Trim(sl.Text), ...)`

Comment: @JamesB, CommaText surrounds the items with " as QuoteChar, maybe this is not what the OP wants

Comment: @whosrdaddy, QuoteChar is only used when needed (i.e. when blanks or quotes are found in the strings). Nevertheless, DelimitedText acts the  same way concerning quotes. CommaText only uses fixed characters for Delimiter and QuoteChar.

Comment: @UweRaabe, indeed it only quotes strings with spaces and quotes, but maybe it is not desired.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to use the [DelimitedText](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TStrings.DelimitedText) property of the `TStringList` class. From the online help

> Use DelimitedText to get or set all the strings in the TStrings object in a single string, separated by the character specified by the Delimiter property.

Answer (score 19):

use the `DelimitedText` property:

```
channelList.Delimiter := ',';
channelList.QuoteChar := ''; // or
channelList.QuoteChar := #0; // for higher delphi versions
aCurrentChannel := channelList.DelimitedText;
```

Comment: `channelList.QuoteChar := '';` does not work anymore,  `channelList.QuoteChar := #0;` - its working

Comment: I'm using XE7 and I got an error: E2010 Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'string'. But in Delphi 6 I always used `QuoteChar:= '';` It depends on unicode?

Comment: Indeed, seems Char type doesn't allow '' but needs #0 in Delphi 11. I consider it counter-intuitive though, will file a report for it at http://quality.embarcadero.com

Answer (score 1):

While you're into string lists i suggest you to cast a look at http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:IJclStringList

```
// var channelList: iJclStringList;
var s: string;

s := JclStringList.Add(['aaa','bbb','ccc '])
         .Split('ddd: eee', ':', False).Trim.Join(',');
```